# Calendar localization in the new codenameone GUI Builder

Tags: codenameone

how can I implement localization for my calendar component in the new codenameone GUI Builder, working in Netbeans IDE. i.e. is there an equivalent of this process described for the old GUI Builder? https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---localizetranslate-my-application-apply-i18nl10n-internationalizationlocalization-to-my-app.html.

Alternatively, how can I then access calendar properties implementing code manually, so that I alter the strings to preferred language?; strings for Month titles, days of the week etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can localize the new GUI builder just like the old one in the same old interface you just don't get the same level of preview. We hope to release a better localization tool moving forward.

To localize the calendar strings use syntax like: `Calendar.Jan`, `Calendar.Feb` etc.

For the days `Calendar.Sunday` etc.